# Stanford_parser_ros fails to build

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

i am trying to build roboframenet but it fails when rosmaking stanfor_parser_ros with the following error message:

> ```
> [javac] /home/kargm/work/ros/other_stacks/roboframenet/stanford_parser_ros/build.xml:30:
> ```
>
> warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
> [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/kargm/work/ros/other_stacks/roboframenet/stanford_parser_ros/build
> [javac] /home/kargm/work/ros/other_stacks/roboframenet/stanford_parser_ros/src/org/ros/nlp/Parser.java:9:
> package org.apache.commons.logging does not exist
> [javac] import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
> [javac]                                  ^
> [javac] /home/kargm/work/ros/other_stacks/roboframenet/stanford_parser_ros/src/org/ros/nlp/Parser.java:10:
> package org.ros.node does not exist
> [javac] import org.ros.node.DefaultNodeFactory;
> [javac]                    ^
> [javac] /home/kargm/work/ros/other_stacks/roboframenet/stanford_parser_ros/src/org/ros/nlp/Parser.java:11:
> package org.ros.message does not exist

(...)

> [javac]
> /home/kargm/work/ros/other_stacks/roboframenet/stanford_parser_ros/src/org/ros/nlp/Parser.java:18:
> package org.ros.message.stanford_parser_msgs does not exist
> [javac] import org.ros.message.stanford_parser_msgs.SquashedParseTreeNode;
> [javac]                                            ^
> [javac] /home/kargm/work/ros/other_stacks/roboframenet/stanford_parser_ros/src/org/ros/nlp/Parser.java:20:
> package edu.stanford.nlp.ling does not exist

(...)

It says,  package org.apache.commons.logging does not exist but the libcommons-logging-java system dependency is installed on my Ubuntu.

It also cannot find other packages which i have installed... is there something wrong with my rosjava installation? Or is it a problem of the ros.properties-file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28761/stanford_parser_ros-fails-to-build/) by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roboframenet is experimental software that no longer works with the latest rosjava.  It will need to be ported to the newer APIs in order to get past these compilation issues.

Also, the rosjava build system is being overhauled to be pure Maven (no rosmake) in order to better leverage the existing Ant/Maven infrastructure that Java provides.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3